# Login issue in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, mysql, password, phpmyadmin, bug

I'm facing currently an issue with my wordpress site, i don't know exactly what happened but when i try to login from **/wp-admin** i enter my password and i connect, but naturaly after the session dies i am obliged to login again and enter my password, when i do it says that my password is wrong and i use the option "forgot password" to create a new one.

The same thing happens everytime i am disconnected from wordpress, the password seems to change, and i am forced to go through the same process again to reset my password.

When i checked closely from the database PhpMyAdmin i noticed that indeed the hashed password changes everytime by itself.

I have no idea why this is happening, if anyone of you have a clue, please let me know !

Thank you

Comment: The password would only change without your knowledge if you've been hacked. It would be best to contact a WP security company to identify the issues and clean up your site, as most often hackers place several exploits in sites to be able to regain access.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Much appreciated !
I just found out the cause of the issue.
Let me clarify, that when i can't connect to my account, it doesn't tell me that my password is wrong, it just redirects me again to the login page, and i can only make it work through setting a new password.

Apparently, the issue was coming from the plugin Really Simple SSL which i use on various websites and never gave me a problem, but on this particular website it was just a pain in the ass!

Just thought you should know for future members who might face the same issue !